# Is it possible to count how many button clicks in the Word ribbon with VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a custom button on a custom tab in the Word ribbon that opens a template. I'd like to know how many times this button is clicked, so I know how many times the template is used.

Is it possible to count this using Word VBA? If yes, how?

Comment: Ben's answer below seems like a good approach, however this only will keep track of the count during the application's session. Depending on your needs, that may (or may not) suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the sub of the custom button just add a variable that counts up by one each time its run. You could then display that somewhere else or return in a MsgBox or however you like.

```
Sub customMacro()
    Static Count As Long
    Count = Count + 1
    Documents.Open FileName:="template.doc"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, Ben. As David Zemens says, it'll keep track of the count during the session, but I think I'll store the counts (start with 0) and add every click. Let's see how this works.